# jquery datetime picker is not working after jquery ajax called?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am using jquery datepicker on jsp page and when i call ajax to load some data from server   and on success of ajax data loads to div tag after that i cant see the datepicker.

**when i click on textfield i shows date picker but
on click of button i m loading data through ajax and after that date picker is not working**

```
 <html>
 <head>      
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   $('#end_dtnw').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
   $("#reportList").click(function(){ 
   $.ajax({
         type : 'Post',
         url : 'www.google.com',
         data: "prjid="+prjid,
         beforeSend : function(){
         },
         success : function(data){
             $('#newreportdata').html(data);
         },
         error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
         }
        }); 
  });
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="end_dtnw" id="end_dtnw" />
  <input type="button" name="reportList" id="reportList" />
  <div id="newreportdata"></div>
  </body> 
  </html>

  //consider that my coding is correct.....
```

[image]

**THANKS** in advanced......

Comment: It seems like you haven't shown us the problematic bits of your code. What you posted seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/william/yRwqF/.

Comment: @ William Niu 
hey check my post when i click on click me button i call to some page through ajax and after ajax loads data to page that picker did not opened 
before ajax call it works fine but after ajax call there might be some problem

Comment: sure, but if `#newreportdata` does not contain `#end_dtnw`, it should not matter if you make an AJAX call. What is a typical content in the `data` in `success: function(data)`?

Comment: success: function(data)? data contains html table code which is loaded in <div id="newreportdata"></div>

Comment: here's one with ajax call, and still works: http://jsfiddle.net/william/yRwqF/4/. My point stands: as long as you don't touch `#end_dtnw`, it should just keep working.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the HTML you are loading has a problem.  Care to show us that?  Then we could see the problem.  Also, show us the HTML for `#end_dtnw` and `#newreportdata`.

---

Thanks for the edit -- your HTML does not match the screen shot-- I don't see the from and to text etc.  Please show the code that has the problem or reproduce in a reduced state.

You can also make a test case on jsfiddle.com and show me that -- then we can all see the error happening.

Comment: #end_dtnw this is id of following textfield 
 
<input type="text" name="end_dtnw" id="end_dtnw" />

when i click on this text field it opens datepicker and insert selected date to that textfield

and #newreportdata id id of div

<div id="newreportdata"></div>

data loaded from ajax is displayed in that div

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article about the datepicker using the live() function in jQuery(AJAX):

http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-ajax-and-livequery/

This can help you.