# Datepicker doesn't display the date on the text after an ajax call

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a `div` ided as `inPatientDecision`, the contents for which are loaded dynamically through an Ajax call. The loaded content has a few HTML datepicker elements with class attribute set to `datePicker`. To instantiate the Jquery UI Datepicker calendar to those elements, I've set `$(\'.datePicker\').datePicker();` on ajax `complete`. The ajax call is:

```
jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',
             data:{'inpatientDecisionId': '6'},   
             url:'/myproje/um/editDecision/13',
             success:function(data,textStatus){
             jQuery('#inPatientDecision').html(data);},
             error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){},
             complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){
                  $(\'.datePicker\').datepicker();
             }});; 
 alt="Edit Authorization Decision" src="/everest/images/edit_icon.png">
```

Now when the content loads and the datepicker element is clicked, I sure can get the calendar displayed. But when I select any date, the selected date is not displayed to the input boxes.

Sure something like this has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241530/jquery-datetime-picker-is-not-working-after-jquery-ajax-called) before but the solutions provided haven't been much helpful to me (possibly neither to the previous OP, an answer hasn't been accepted).

Answer (score 0):

Please see my updated code below

```
jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',
         data:{'inpatientDecisionId': '6'},   
         url:'/myproje/um/editDecision/13',
         success:function(data,textStatus){

         jQuery('#inPatientDecision').html(data);
         $(\'.datePicker\').datepicker();

         },
         error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){},
});;
```

Basically complete and success would execute together, so i just placed datepicker after you place html in success section.

Hopefully this should work.

Comment: I'm afraid but its not working. I've now begun to think that the problem in not in the ajax call. I removed the `$(\'.datePicker\').datepicker();` part from the ajax call. And after the content has been loaded through the ajax into the desired div, I ran `$('.datePicker').datePicker()` on the Firebug console. That would give me the calendar on the input elements with class attribute `.datePicker` but I can't get the selected date displayed on the input element.

Comment: Just confirming did you removed "\" character inside $(\'.datePicker\'), also if even this does not work, it seems when you tried to bind datepicker these elements where not in DOM

Comment: But if the datepicker was not bound to these elements, the calendar wouldn't have shown up, have it? The calendar is showing up but the selected date is not being displayed at the input box.